# django-registration and CSS files

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I have recently plugged in the django-registration module to enable user signup and validation. However, when I do an extends base.html, my CSS objects are missing.

Does anyone know why this happens? I have everything under the registration folder and my media files are in the folder /media. Everyother page works (i.e displays the CSS objects properly), except the pages from /registration.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Pardon me if this is a basic question: new to django here.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are extending the correct "base.html" by doing a show source in the browser.

Some of the sample templates come with their own base.html file to show you how it's done and your registration module may be including that by mistake.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have checked the extends base a couple of times, and also looked at the page source. on the page source, when I click on the CSS files, it does say "<title>Page not found at /accounts/login/media/default.advanced.css</title>" Does this mean that Django is looking for the CSS files on /accounts/login/media?. I even tried changing this path now (by giving an absolute path to the cSS), but it still does not work. Strange.

Comment: Ah!  You are using relative paths without a base.  Add the following line to your base.html  <base href='/'>